# python split method: avoiding the "not enough values to unpack" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

When using the split method in python, if you do not assign the exact correct number of values it fails with the following error:

> 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

> 

In this simple example, when a variable doesn't have 4 values how can I assign an empty variable in it's place?  The best solution I could come up with is counting the number of commas (delimiter) and then using a different split statement depending on the number but there has to be a better way.  Using split in perl behaves differently, if you wrote equivalent perl code to the below and if the 4th value didn't exist it would automatically assign "undef" to col4 without causing the program to crash.  I want to do the equivalent in python.

```
colors = ['blue, purple, red',
          'black, brown',
          'orange',
          'pink, white, yellow']

for x in colors:
    (col1, col2, col3, col4) = x.split(',')
```

Comment: split into a single list variable `color_list = x.split(',')`, then you can pad out with None with `while len(color_list) < 4: color_list.append(None)`.  Perl make a lot of variables magically come into existence, which can lead to lots of hard to find bugs.  The real question is why you need four fixed name variables when you could just make your code deal with the list whatever its length is.

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself with variables called `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` etc, for any `xxx`, you need to replace those variables with a list (or other data structure).  It's short, it's more flexible, and it's less error prone.

Comment: just keep it as a list.

Comment: I shortened and simplified the code as much as possible in my original question.   The purpose of this is that I have a table with 4 columns and I need to add a variable into each column and when one doesn't exist just leave it blank.   I ended up doing something similar to what @Malcom suggested.   I check the length of the list and if it's not 4 I create blank variables.   I was hoping there was an automatic way to do this like you can in perl in a single line =  (col1, col2, col3, col4) = split(',', $var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add ',,,' and get the first 4 elements, e.g.:

```py
colors = ['blue, purple, red',
          'black, brown',
          'orange',
          'pink, white, yellow']

for x in colors:
    (col1, col2, col3, col4) = (x + ',,,').split(',')[:4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to split it into a list then check the length of each sub-list as @Malcolm said:

```
for x in colors:
    print(x.split(', '))

['blue', 'purple', 'red']
['black', 'brown']
['orange']
['pink', 'white', 'yellow']
```

---

If you are looking to unpack lists but you do not know the quantity of elements then you can also use `*` unpacking operator:

```
colors = ['blue, purple, red',
          'black, brown',
          'orange',
          'pink, white, yellow']
```

---

```
for x in colors:
    a,*b = x.split(', ')
    print(a,b)

#output

blue ['purple', 'red']
black ['brown']
orange []
pink ['white', 'yellow']
```

**First element of the list will always be in `a` and remaining elements will be present in `b`.
It will work for empty lists as well. If there is no second element `b` will be an empty list.**

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the list created from `split()` into a custom function that will always yield 4 values(defaults to `None`):

```
def unpack4(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    for _ in range(4):
        yield next(it, None)


colors = ["orange",
          "black,brown",
          "blue,purple,red",
          "pink,white,yellow,cyan",
          "green,violet,indigo,maroon,aqua",
          ]

for c in colors:
    (col1, col2, col3, col4) = unpack4(c.split(","))
    print(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Output:

```
orange None None None
black brown None None
blue purple red None
pink white yellow cyan
green violet indigo maroon
```

*Note the lack of `aqua` in the 5th example and this wouldn't cover the case of an empty string `""`*
But as others have commented, this seems like a poor programming practice...